# MVC HTML Helper custom namespace

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

how I can create something like this: Html.MyApp.ActionLink()?
Thanks.

Comment: In that context, what is MyApp? A type? A local object? A controller? A route? A view? What?

Comment: I would like to have a root for all of my helpers. So instead to have helpers like Html.MyHelperForLinks or Html.MyHelperForText, I want this: Html.MyApp.MyHelperForLinks, Html.MyApp.MyHelperForText, Html.MyApp.MyHelperForTextBox, and so on...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this. The only way you can add to the Html class is via an extension method. You cannot add "Extension Properties", which is what would be required for you to use `Html.MyApp`. The closest you could come is `Html.MyApp().Method(...)`

Your best bet is probably to either include them as extension methods on Html, or create a new class completely (eg. `MyAppHtml.Method(...)` or `MyApp.Html.Method(...)`). There was a blog post around recently specifically showing an "Html5" class with these methods, but unfortunately my Google skills are failing me, and I can't find it :(

#### Added 13 Oct 2011 *as asked in comment*

To do something like `Html.MyApp().ActionLink()` you need to create an extension method on `HtmlHelper`, that returns an instance of a class with your custom method:

```
namespace MyHelper
{
    public static class MyHelperStuff
    {
        // Extension method - adds a MyApp() method to HtmlHelper
        public static MyHelpers MyApp(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            return new MyHelpers();
        }
    }

    public class MyHelpers
    {
        public IHtmlString ActionLink(string blah)
        {
            // Wrap the html in an MvcHtmlString otherwise it'll be HtmlEncoded and displayed to the user as HTML :(
            return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<a href=\"#\">{0}</a>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(blah)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: You'll need to import the namespace this class is in in `Web.config`, like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="MyHelper"/>
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

The change in the Web.Config file needs to be done in the config file for the view, not the global one

Comment: If this answers the question, you're welcome to mark it as the answer ;)

Comment: How I can do something like this "Html.MyApp().Method(...)"?

Comment: Sure, but there is an error. "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class", for both MyHelperStuff and MyHelpers classes.

Comment: Sorry, you need to mark the class as static (updated my sample)

Comment: Does not work. The same error for the "MyHelpers" only. I tried to change something else with no lucky.

Comment: The `MyHelpers` class should not have any extension methods - make sure you don't have the word `this` in the `MyHelpers` class anywhere.

Comment: The problem was the word this in my extensions. Seems to works fine now, thank you very much.